# ¿Por qué no me cuenta los puntos de todos los cuadrantes?

Tags: c

Quiero que en el programa se vea la cantidad de puntos que hay en cada cuadrante de un plano y cuando lo ejecuto, siempre que pongo 4 puntos, uno en cada cuadrante, me cuenta solo los puntos del primer y segundo cuadrante. Podrian alguien decirme que hice mal? gracias. El codigo es en C. La cantidad es la cantidad de puntos que el usuario debe introducir.  Un punto tiene una posicion en x y en y.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, cantidad, f, cont1, cont2, cont3, cont4;
    printf("Ingresa la cantidad: ");
    scanf("%i",&cantidad);
    cont1=0;
    cont2=0;
    cont3=0;
    cont4=0;
    for(f=1;f<=cantidad;f++){
        printf("Ingrese la coordenada de x:");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        printf("Ingrese la coordenada de y:");
        scanf("%i", &x);
       if(x > 0 && y > 0)
        {
            cont1++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(x < 0 && y >0)
            {
                cont2++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(x< 0 && y <0)
                {
                    cont3++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(x > 0 && y < 0)
                    {
                        cont4++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Los puntos del primer cuadrante son: ");
    printf("%i", cont1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Los puntos del segundo cuadrante son: ");
    printf("%i", cont2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Los puntos del tercer cuadrante son: ");
    printf("%i", cont3);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Los puntos del cuarto cuadrante son: ");
    printf("%i", cont4);
    getch();
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En lugar de saludar, coloca en el título el problema específico que estás teniendo. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta. Además, explica cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el obtenido actualmente.

Comment: fijate el segundo scanf dentro del for... debe ir &y en lugar de &x, estas asignando 2 veces la variable x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error de tipeo.

Escribiste 2 veces:

```
scanf("%i", &x);
```

Cuando la segunda vez debería ser:

```
scanf("%i", &y);
```

---

Por cierto, puedes conectar ifs de esta forma:

```
if(x > 0 && y > 0)
{
    cont1++;
}
else if(x < 0 && y >0)
{
    cont2++;
}
else if(x< 0 && y < 0)
{
    cont3++;
}
else if(x > 0 && y < 0)
{
    cont4++;
}
```

Cada vez que aumentas el nivel de indentado significa que tu código es más difícil de leer. Con esto no quiero decir que no lo indentes sino que intentes hacer el código de otra manera.

Comment: Dale, gracias Mateo!!!